# Unable to import bunch of libraries on VS code (jupyter notebook python)

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, import

I recently got a Mac and I'm unable to import a list of libraries on visual studio code. When I import just one library on single cell it worked but when I try lots of imports it fails.

[image]

Comment: Those libraries don't come with Python. Have you installed them?

Comment: Hi Chris! Yes sure, I have installed them. The problem is VS importing then correctly but afterwards it says I haven't import them.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have switched the python interpreter, and the new environment has not installed the modules which you want to import, such as `numpy`.

Could you try to switch the python interpreter in the Jupyter NoteBook?

[image]